# How can I close my Navigation Bar with a click on a link in that bar (One-Site-Page)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im working on my first website. I started creating a navbar but i want it responsive. The version with the burger goes from `0-750px`. I want, that the navbar closes when i click on a link in it. (In the normal laptop and pc mode everything is fine). I can use jQuery, html, css, and javascrpit (Bootstrapper destroys my website). I would be glad if u can help me, heres my code! Btw I created this navbar with help from a video from Dev Ed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXkqy0b4M5g
Thank you!

JavaScript

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s`;
      }
    });
    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
  });
};
navSlide();
```

CSS

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Sora";
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-links li {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  bottom: 5px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.nav-links a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80vh;
    top: 114.19px;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    margin: 0;
    right: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform ease-in 0, 5s;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#opti">Öffnungszeiten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#adress">Adresse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#costs">Preisliste</a></li>
    <li><a href="#date">Termine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pics">Kundenfotos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rec">Bewertung</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s`;
      }
    });
    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
  });
  navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      burger.click();
    });
  });
};
navSlide();
```